# Options for linting Cython code

Tags: python, cython, pylint

I have a Cython module that I would like to lint [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style, however `pylint` syntax errors on Cython `cdef` syntax.  Does anyone have a suggestion about how to maintain Python coding standards for Cython code?

Comment: I've not heard of an tools which can do this -- Although the Cython community might be grateful if you managed to figure out how to do it yourself ;-)

Comment: I think you should piggy-back on `cython` the compiler to detect which blocks of code are C and which are Python. Once that is done, you could probably hack the linter and/or map Python blocks to syntactically-equivalent Python code that can be linted with existing tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Sublime Text editor with SublimeLinter [Flake8 package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter-flake8).

My Flake8 config is:

```
"flake8": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [
                "--doctests"
            ],
            "builtins": "",
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore": "",
            "ignore_match": {
                "pyx": [
                    "SyntaxError"
                ]
            },
            "jobs": "1",
            "max-complexity": 7,
            "max-line-length": null,
            "select": "",
            "show-code": false
        },
```

**"ignore_match"** key is used to define regular expressions that ignore some reported errors by a linter.

In this case I used it to ignore syntaxis errors in **.pyx** files. You can define new expressions to meet your needs.

Sorry because it's not a Cython linter, it's just a trick to make Python linter useful.

More info in [sublimelinter official docs](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/linter_settings.html#ignore-match).

Answer (score 5):

Although not command-line based, [PyCharm claims to have Cython support](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/cython-support.html). Unfortunately, it's only available on the paid-version "Professional Edition".

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, you can use [cython-lint](https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/cython-lint)

Install with

```
$ pip install cython-lint
```

Or use as pre-commit hook:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/cython-lint
    rev: v0.10.1
    hooks:
    -   id: cython-lint
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending off @j-mulet's answer, a useful example is that Pandas keeps its own [cython.cfg](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/flake8/cython.cfg) file as Cython-specific rules to search for across .pyx files.

```
[flake8]
filename = *.pyx,*.pxd
select = E501,E302,E203,E111, ...
```

You can then call tell flake8 where this lives:

```sh
$ flake8 -config <path-to-cython.cfg>
```